# Are technical questions about how to use a particular product on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm thinking about questions more restricted in scope than "how should I play this particular chord on the guitar"; for example:

> I have a "Brand B Model M" synthesizer which features a sequencer. In the "pattern mode", how can I avoid conflicts when chaining consecutive sections with different time signatures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course !
This website is also intended to be used by experts !
And expert questions may not be limited to generic questions.

People may have an issue on a specific product and the answer may be specific to that product. A wider scope question may not help.

**BUT**, if the question can be generalized, it should be rewritten to be as generic as possible. But only if it doesn't change the question meaning.

Comment: might this include questions like "How do I extract a certain piece of sound out of a sound file using ableton live 8?

Comment: Hum no. This is "Musical Practice and Performance". Your question is about editing. It should belong to AVP (Audio-Video Production) http://avp.stackexchange.com/ and should be on-topic there.